# How to add multipule values in single column of hbase

Tags: hbase, schema

I have `Geo Co-ordinates` to be saved in `HBase`, for a single point I'm saving with column names as `latitude` and `longitude`, but when I have a line instead of point,I'll have to save 6 `Geo Co-ordinates` into `HBase`. 
The no.of `Geo Co-ordinates` varies. So, how to save such data into `HBase` ?

Can anything be done with column name, column family or anything else in the schema ?

What I need is to save in same column `latitude` and `longitude`, it should have one value each for a point, 6 values each for a line and so on...

Comment: It depends of queries that you are interested in. Each point or line have an identifier to use as rowkey?

Comment: no they don't, its just `latitude` and `longitude` values that I receive and need to save them

Answer (score 2):

Columns in HBase can be dynamically generated, you don't have to specify them in a schema. Given that you can have:

- columns `longitude` and `latitude` for points
- columns `cord1`, `cord2`, ..., `cord6` for lines

Another option is to always have columns `longitude` and `latitude` and format the values according to whether you have a point or a line. For instance, if your encoding has a fixed length of 4 bytes, you'd have

- points:

  - `longitude` = [0xdeadbeef]
  - `latitude` = [0xbadcaffe]
- lines:

  - `longitude` = [0xdeadbeef 0xcafebabe 0x000000]
  - `latitude` = [0xbadcaffe 0x111111 0xdeadbeef]

When querying the data you know whether it's a point or a line based on the length of the values or you could store a tag in another column.

Comment: What would you use as HBase table's rowkey?

Comment: That depends on how he plans to query the data. If anything is fine then a hash, a random value or a UUID are all valid options.